# I don't have a wireless connection

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

I have no wireless on my desktop. When I try to connect using the wireless icon on the panel, it says:
`Ethernet Network (Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller disconnected.`

How can I fix this to have my desktop connect to my wireless router without running an ethernet cable?

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 11
       serial: d8:cb:8a:7b:fc:a0
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:30 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:b3:93:07
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20u9
       serial: 02:07:3d:60:33:62
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.42 link=yes multicast=yes



Usage:  rfkill [options] command
Options:
    --version   show version (0.5-1ubuntu3 (Ubuntu))
Commands:
    help
    event
    list [IDENTIFIER]
    block IDENTIFIER
    unblock IDENTIFIER
where IDENTIFIER is the index no. of an rfkill switch or one of:
    <idx> all wifi wlan bluetooth uwb ultrawideband wimax wwan gps fm nfc

 ifconfig
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:7b:fc:a0  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp0s20u9 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:07:3d:60:33:62  
          inet addr:192.168.42.42  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::985e:c706:c5eb:69a0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:518 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:584 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:323980 (323.9 KB)  TX bytes:105057 (105.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:57001 (57.0 KB)  TX bytes:57001 (57.0 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
```

Comment: and im using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You don't seem to have  a wireless card, from the commands all of them are for ethernet: `description: Ethernet interface`. Here's is mine for wireless: `description: Wireless interface`

Comment: Kindly run this command in the terminal then edit your question and include the result there: `rfkill list`

Comment: before i made the switch i had wireless and even after i made the switch i was wireless. as of 3 days ago it wont connect or pull it up. do i need to get a new card or do i have to run an ethernet cable?

Comment: Usage: rfkill [options] command
Options:
 --version show version (0.5-1ubuntu3 (Ubuntu))
Commands:
 help
 event
 list [IDENTIFIER]
 block IDENTIFIER
 unblock IDENTIFIER
where IDENTIFIER is the index no. of an rfkill switch or one of:
 <idx> all wifi wlan bluetooth uwb ultrawideband wimax wwan gps fm nfc

Comment: The command was: `rfkill list`

Comment: Let's see if we can debug it..

Comment: when i did that it didnt do anything

Comment: You mean it had no output? That's strange...let's try these two then: `ifconfig` and `lspci` Run them one after another and include the output here.

Comment: Are you using a USB adapter? Please post of `lsusb` then.